# Could using a component method as an async callback in componentWillUnmount cause a memory leak?

Tags: reactjs

Calling `setState` in an async function inside `componentWillUnmount` can cause a memory leak: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-work-with-react-the-right-way-to-avoid-some-common-pitfalls-fc9eb5e34d9e

```
public componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe().catch(this.onError);
}
```

Given the above, will this also produce a memory leak? The component could unmount before `unsubscribe` finishes, so the component's `onError` method won't be invoked until after the unmounting. Will the component then be garbage collected or not?

Comment: What is `subscription`  and what does `unsubscribe` return?

Comment: `unsubscribe()` merely returns a promise, I didn't think the implementation details were important, just that `this.onError` could be invoked *after* the component is unmounted.

Comment: Since it's your own implementation, it may matter. If `unsubscribe` does not necessarily settle immediately, it may cause a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article doesn't say that `setState` **causes** a memory leak.

> Can’t call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it **indicates** a memory leak in your application.

The problem isn't limited to `setState` or `forceUpdate`. They are just methods that React can track and issue a warning when needed. Their calls indicate that something is going on in component instance after it was unmounted.

That `this` component instance is referenced after unmount means that component instance cannot be garbage-collected until an operation that involves `this` is completed. In case an operation completed immediately, there's no memory leak. In case it took several minutes, there's a leak.

As long as `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` doesn't result in long-running promise or pending promise that will cause `this.onError` to not be called in a short time, and `onError` doesn't contain troublesome code, it shouldn't cause a memory leak. This is an example of the code that belongs to `componentWillUnmount`.

It also may be beneficial to return a promise from hook methods, so they could be spied and chained in tests.